# Rails: showing data in a crosstab

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, crosstab

I'm building an expenditures diary and therefore need a crosstab in my view. The app has an expenditures table. Every record in that table is a single expenditure holding (amongst others) "Value" (as integer), "Day" (as date) and "Category_ID" (as integer and foreign key).

What I want to do is to display a table that shows a user how much he spent on each category in each month.

Thus I need to do two things:

1. Group all expenditures by month and category
2. Display that in a view

**In other terms I want to go from:**

[image]

**To:**

[image]

How can I achieve that? Have been searching for a while now but did not find a suitable solution.

Additionally I want to display not the "Category_ID" but the category's name (from the category join table).

**UPDATE:
I tried the following so far:**

```
@expenditures = Expenditure.where(:user_id => current_user)
@grouped_exp = @expenditures.includes(:category).group("DATE_TRUNC('month', day)", :name).sum(:value)
```

Which gives me now:

```
[[[2016-08-01 00:00:00 UTC, "housing | electricity"], -31.0], [[2016-09-01 00:00:00 UTC, "other | pharmacy & drugstore"], -9.5], [[2016-08-01 00:00:00 UTC, "financials | salary"], 2913.92], [[2016-10-01 00:00:00 UTC, "housing | internet"], -26.06], ... ]
```

So I have now for each category at each month a sum. However, I don't know if this is the correct way and if yes, what would be the next steps.

Comment: I added an update in my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table you want to create can not be done like this. It seems to have dynamic columns corresponding to months of a year. This can not be done using ActiveRecord. You'd have to use SQL directly and programatically generate the query always selecting specific date ranges per column. Probably not a good idea unless you are some SQL hero.

What you need is something more like this

```
Category.joins(:expenditures).
  where("expenditures.user_id = ?", current_user).
  group("categories.id, DATE_TRUNC('month', day)").
  select("categories.name, DATE_TRUNC('month', day) AS month, SUM(value) AS sum")
```

Which will give you records like

```
r = records.first
r.name => 'Some category'
r.month => '2016-10'
r.sum => 55
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this:

```
@expenditures
  .joins(:category)
  .select('DATE_TRUNC('month', day) as day, category_id, sum(value) as total')
  .group('day, category_id, total')
```

Comment: Ok tried that. If I do <%= @grouped_exp %> in my view I get: #<Expenditure::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fe9fc55ab48>

Comment: If I do <%= @grouped_exp.to_a %> I get: PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "expenditures.category_id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: SELECT DATE_TRUNC('month', day) as day, category_id, sum(val...

Comment: then something's wrong with the query, run it in console and try to get the first value. You'll see the SQL query executed as well the error

Comment: Added the other fields to the group statement. Can you give it another try?

Comment: I ran your first proposal in console producing: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "expenditures.category_id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: SELECT DATE_TRUNC('month', day) as day, category_id, sum(val...
                                                ^
: SELECT DATE_TRUNC('month', day) as day, category_id, sum(value) FROM "expenditures" INNER JOIN "categories" ON "categories"."id" = "expenditures"."category_id" GROUP BY "expenditures"."day"

Comment: Your updated code: PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  aggregate functions are not allowed in GROUP BY
LINE 1: ...ECT DATE_TRUNC('month', day) as day, category_id, sum(value)...